# what is the correct mysql syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me with this syntax.  Is this correct?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM axispl WHERE companyname LIKE $searchterm% LIMIT 11");
```

In few examples on the net I have seen ` symbol being used to enclose axispl or companyname.  In few they are not present.  What is the difference?

My database has 2 columns.  First has company names.  Second has the category they fall in to.  I basically want the query to select 11 of these pairs when the company name matches the searchterm.

Should I mention SELECT * or should I mention SELECT companyname, axiscategory ? (these are the names of the two columns).

If the above syntax is not correct, what should I change?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the search term with single quotes.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM axispl WHERE companyname LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($searchterm)."%' LIMIT 11");
```

It does not really matter if you use `SELECT *` or specify the columns - the latter is usually a *little* bit faster but it usually doesn't matter if you need all columns anyway.

Regarding your quoting question:

- Always escape strings you pass into a query.
- Use single quotes to quote strings used in a query
- Backticks are used to quote database/table/column names and only necessary if they collide with reserved keywords.

Comment: Based on your feedback, I have changed the following code: mysql_connect('localhost','username','password'); mysql_select_db('pl') or die( "Unable to select database"); to PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pl;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password'); Is it correct or do I have to pass this to a variable (in the PDO tutorial it is being passed to a variable db; what is the purpose of that?)

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are used to ensure that the thing they contain is treated as a database, table or column name, whatever the context calls for. As well as making it more human-readable, it allows you to use literally any column name, including reserved words such as `count`, `timestamp`, `from`, numeric column names `25`,`50`,`100` and all kind of crazy symbols if you really want.

However, that aside, your search term should be in quotes, because it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference?

There is no difference.

The backtick symbol is used with identifiers that are not valid as Identifiers names. For instance, if you have a column named as a reserved word, in this case you have to use the backtick symbol to escape them.

In your case, it is optional to use ` symbol with your columns since the are valid identifiers' names.

> Should I mention SELECT * or should I mention SELECT companyname,
>   axiscategory ?

It is recommended not to use the `SELECT *` and name your columns' names explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

First off, telling which columns you are returning is always a good idea so you can make sure to only return the actual data needed. For a table this small it might not matter much but what if you have 50 columns and 100 000 rows and you just want a list of the first two columns?

Quoting the column- and tablenames is a good practice, while not necessary all the time it saves you when you when you happen to use a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) (like SELECT, FROM, ADD, DELETE etc) in a name.

Also in your query, you need to singlequote the query for LIKE since it want's a string.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `companyname`, `axiscategory` FROM `axispl` WHERE `companyname` LIKE '$searchterm%' LIMIT 11");
```